# How to create servlet-context.xml & servlet-context-dispatcher.xml files for spring

Tags: spring, servletcontextlistener

In my spring spring controller I have written a @PostConstruct configured function, but the problem is that it is involked 2 times when i run the project.Below is my web.xml and servlet-context.xml files.

web.xml :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>SaveMoneyOauth</display-name>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>


            <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>       

            <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>

            <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>  
                /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml,  
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
            </context-param>


            <!-- Spring Security -->

            <filter>
                    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
            </filter>

            <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
                    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
            </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
            <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myproject" />
            <mvc:annotation-driven>
            <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
            </mvc:message-converters>
            </mvc:annotation-driven>

            <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
            </bean>  

            <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SaveIt"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>com.example.myproject</value>
        </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    </beans>
```

I found this problem is because i have configured servlet-context.xml as both the ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet. So to avoid this problem i have to split this xml file sperate for these two.So i changed the DispatcherServlet as below in web.xml

```
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SaveMoneyOauth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context-dispatcher.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
```

But how can i split the file codes to servlet-context.xml and servlet-context-dispatcher.xml? What should i write in both this file?Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

what you load in via ContextLoaderListener, should be **root WebApplicationContext**

> The root WebApplicationContext should contain all the infrastructure
>   beans that should be shared between your other contexts and Servlet
>   instances. These inherited beans can be overridden in the
>   servlet-specific scope, and you can define new scope-specific beans
>   local to a given Servlet instance.

Beans that you load via DispatcherServlet is application specific servlet context and it inherit all the beans that you defined in root webapplication context.

so ideally something like application specific beans such session factory, transaction manager and other relevant infrastructure beans should go in your root webapplication context. Beans such as controllers and view resolvers should go in your servlet context

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet